# (MQTT message) scheduling using blocks of time

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, mqtt, scheduling

I'm currently working on a gradle project where I need to send messages over an MQTT queue to a service. This is all using the Java Spring (boot) framework. A small part of this project, is that I need to be able to put multiple blocks of time (e.g. 10:30 to 15:30) in the application properties file. The objective of these time blocks is to schedule 2 separate frequencies the program must send messages to the queue. During peak frequency I need to send messages every second and during low frequency every 30 seconds.

Example properties file:

```
frequency.low=[[0:00,6:30],[10:45,15:30],[19:00,0:00]]
frequency.peak=[[6:30,10:30],[15:30,19:00]]
```

The way the time blocks are put in the properties file can be changed entirely. I currently need a way to schedule these time blocks. 
I have already tried using the `@Scheduled(cron = ...)` annotation, but that was too limiting. I know how I can set this up using `ScheduledExecutorService`, but I was wondering if there are some third-party/gradle libraries out there that I can use for this specific use case?

Thanks in advance!